# White Screen in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

White Screen When I use params in my react router:

AppRouter.js:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
class AppRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/product/show/:product" element={<ProductDetailsPage/>} />
          </Routes>
    ) 
  }
}

export default AppRoute;
```

Attention: When I use component(with or without params) instead of element I have white screen too

ProductDetailsPage.jsx :

```
    class ProductDetailsPage extends Component {
    
      constructor({match}){
        super();
        this.state = {
            product: match.params.product,
            products: []
          }
      }
.
.
.
.
    }
    
    export default ProductDetailsPage;
```

when I delete match, my page load correctly!

Comment: and what is the error shown in DevTools -> Console?

Comment: You aren't passing any props to the `ProductDetailsPage` page so `match` is undefined and is very likely throwing an error when it attempts to further access `match.params`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `match` you can use `useParams hook` from `react-router-dom` to access `product` like below:

```
 import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

 const ProductDetails = () => {
     const {product} = useParams()
 }
```

I've used this in `functional component` but you can also use it in `class component`.

And one more thing if this doesn't work either then I think you are having a problem because you have `product` two(2) times in your `path` but I'm not sure about this.